# Linux find and replace from command line

Tags: regex, linux, sed, command-line

I'm looking for a linux command line script to do the following.

Assume I have a file

```
ABC|1|READ11|Reading|1
ABj|2|READ11|Reading|2
CBD|3|WRIT11|Reading|3
BCD|4|READ11|Reading|4
CDE|5|WRIT11|Reading|5
CBA|6|READ11|Reading|6
```

for every line that start with the letter 'C', if it has 'WRIT11', replace with 'REPL11'

File after script

```
ABC|1|READ11|Reading|1
ABj|2|READ11|Reading|2
CBD|3|REPL11|Reading|3
BCD|4|READ11|Reading|4
CDE|5|REPL11|Reading|5
CBA|6|READ11|Reading|6
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this:

```
sed 's/\(^C.*\)WRIT11/\1REPL11/g' your_file
```

Explanation:

`s/search_this/replace_it_with_this/g` s at the beginning is for search, the g at the end means globally, not just for one line.

In the search_this part the part within `\(` and `\)` can be written as `\1` in the replace_it_with_this part.

The `^C` means there's a C at the beginning of the line and the followed `.` means any character and the `*` means that the preceeding character can occur not at all or multiple times.

Comment: Or maybe shorter without backreference : `sed '/^C/s/WRIT11/REPL11/' file`

Comment: Found this resource to help simulate the command:
https://sed.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
awk -F'|' '($1 ~ /^C.*$/) && ($3 =="WRIT11")                      \
           {print $1"|"$2"|REPL11|"$4"|"$5; next;}{print;}' file
```

Comment: You can also write as : `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} $1 ~ /^C/ && $3 == "WRIT11"{$3="REPL11"}1' file`